# Can I create instances of other classes inside the constructor of my class?

Tags: java, constructor, instance

Sorry for the ambiguity. Editing the question
I want to create instances of class B and class C inside the constructor of class A. 
I want to know what the cons of doing that are.

Comment: Yes. No problems with it, this is called dependency injection.

Comment: This is what parameters are for. Constructor like a normal method can have parameters and this is normal to pass them to it.

Comment: The title denotes exactly the opposite of **passing** instances of other classes (B, C) to A. So, In the title you're actually asking about the **instantiatiation** of the classes B and C inside of A's constructor, e.g. about creating objects of type B and C inside A's constructor (which is bad, resulting in tight coupling). The title should be like in the question.

Comment: Please make the title and the question consistent.  Currently the title is the exact opposite of the question.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I do this in the constructor for A ?

Yes, like this:

```
class A {
  A(B b, C c) { /* do something with b and c */ }
}
```

> Are there any problems with such an approach?

This is a pattern called [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection), which is a good approach to maintain loose coupling between software components.

That's not to say that one could think of *no* problems with it; merely this is a widely-used pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can pass the instances of B and C to A's constructor. And there is no problem with such an approach.